# is it ok to dequeue default parent stylesheet from custom page templates in child theme?

Tags: child-theme

I have created twenty fifteen child theme and am using enqueue to add

styles into it.

I have an HTML layout of a page and i want to convert it into a custom WordPress page template but i have a doubt that if i don't remove default parent style sheet
which is inherited by my child theme then my template will not look same as HTML template .

So is it fine to dequeue default parent style from some pages ? you guys also do this for creating custom template from HTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you need to dequeue parent stylesheet, go ahead. No problem with that. From the point of programming there is no problem. But as a developer I would suggest to override the stylesheet from your child theme. In the end your thinking matters. There are various ways to accomplish anything. Have fun !

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer . don't you think overriding will be more time consuming in case i have lot of differences between my child theme style sheets and parent child sheet ?

Comment: No. But if you think it'll be more time consuming for you then go ahead. There is no problem with that. That's why I told earlier that the decision is entirely your's to take. Hope this is gonna clarify your query. If you are satisfied with the answer please accept the answer. Have a good day.